# While we put elaborate standards to authenticate users (eg via OAuth), why do APIs only need an API Key?

Tags: authentication, api

Today, OAuth is the standard for authenticating Users. It employs an elaborate setup to reduce vulnerabilities.

Yet, when it comes to APIs, the standard is just to have an API Key provided in the HTTP Request Header. Voila, you're in. This is even adopted by Google.

Why is this so? These API endpoints are public!

Comment: *"Why is this so? These API endpoints are public!"* - and the data they provide are public too, at least in case of Google Maps or similar (unfortunately you don't provide details which API you talk about). So you are comparing a) limiting access to private data to only the owner vs. b) limiting access to public data. These are obviously completely different things with different implications for security and for the requirements on protection. Note also the even when using OAuth2 or similar one will usually end up with a session cookie, which is a *"Key inserted in the HTTP Request Header"*.

Comment: OAuth can also be used for API keys. So instead of comparing "OAuth vs API Key" your question needs to be "why not use greater protection for API keys?" And once you reframe your question that way, the answer will end up being a little obvious (because it might not need that extra protection).